# angular 2 when i make a http get request i get 2 calles to controller

Tags: angular, controller, components, http-get

inside my component i make a http request. But when i use it i get 2 calles to my controller which is a huge time issue.
this is my component

```
 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http) {
    }

 viewData(id: string) {

        let c = 1;
        this.http.get('api/Incident/Get?id=' + id).subscribe(res => {
            this.myRootObject = res.json() as RootObject;});
}
ngOnInit() {
        let id = '';
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            id = params['id'];
            if (id != '') {
                this.viewData(id);
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my controller

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
        public ActionResult Get(string id)    
        {
            var res = _backendService.GetAsync("xxx");
            string result = res.Result;

            var dRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
            return Json(dRes);
        }
```

the id is imported correctly but i get 2 calles to my controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: One is probably an `OPTIONS` and a `GET` request. This is because of CORS and caused by the browser if the request doesn't target the same url incl port as where `index.html` was loaded from, or perhaps `params.subscribe()` emits more than one event.

Comment: can u be a little more specific about OPTIONS ? is there any suggestion how to resolve the issue?

Comment: First you need to be more specific about what's actually happening. I only have the information you provided in your question and made some guesses.

Comment: what else do u need from me to post?

Comment: " or perhaps params.subscribe() emits more than one event" That should be easy to find out by adding a `console.log()`

Comment: the first call is being made before i even call the function wich calls the controller

Comment: Then it has to be a different URL that is being called

Comment: sorry if i am being irritating but whe i change subscribe to map i get only one call. whats the difference between map and subscribe?

Comment: It's really hard to tell from here. If you add `console.log()` you should see if the call is made more than once in your code. Then you you need to figure out where multiple calls to your code come from. If your code calls `viewData` only once but the server receives multiple requests, then you need to investigate the received requests (path, headers, ...) to figure out where they come from. Without such details I don't see how I can give more guidance